# GraphQL Java is not detecting kotlin enum correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, enums, graphql-java

I am using graphql spring boot kickstarter - https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot in order to create a spring graphql service. I am building the actual service using kotlin.

I am declaring an enum type in my graphql service, that i have also declared in my kotlin code. This is something i have done for another enum (TimeUnit) but for the new enum (WeekDay) I am getting an error

I have tried creating an explict resolver for the enum type but to no avail.

```
package com.houseshare.server.data.entity

import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.IntArrayType
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.*
import javax.validation.constraints.Size


@Entity
@Table(name = "scheduler")
@TypeDefs(
    TypeDef(
            typeClass = IntArrayType::class,
            defaultForType = Array<Int>::class
    )
)
class Scheduler(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
        @GenericGenerator(
                name = "UUID",
                strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
        ) val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
        @Column(length = 50)
        @Size(max = 50)
        var name: String,
        @Column
        var duration: Int? = null,
        @Column
        @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
        var durationUnit: TimeUnit?  = null,
        @Column
        var frequency: Int?  = null,
        @Column
        @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
        var frequencyUnit: TimeUnit?  = null,
        @Column
        var scheduleDays: Array<Int>?  = null,
        @Column
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
        var scheduleTime: Date?  = null,
        @Column
        var effort: Int?  = null
    ) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Scheduler [id= + ${this.id}]";
    }

    fun getScheduleDaysList() : List<WeekDay>? {
        return scheduleDays?.map { WeekDay.fromInt(it) }
    }

    fun setScheduleDaysList(daysOfWeek : List<WeekDay>?) {
        if(daysOfWeek == null) {
            this.scheduleDays = null;
        } else {
            this.scheduleDays = daysOfWeek.map { it.value }.toTypedArray();
        }
    }

}

enum class TimeUnit {
    MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH
}

enum class WeekDay(val value: Int) {
    MONDAY(1),
    TUESDAY(2),
    WEDNESDAY(3),
    THURSDAY(4),
    FRIDAY(5),
    SATURDAY(6),
    SUNDAY(7);

    companion object {
        fun fromInt(value: Int) = WeekDay.values().first { it.value == value }
    }
}
```

Graphql schema:

```
type Scheduler {
    id: ID!,
    name: String!
    duration: Int,
    durationUnit: TimeUnit,
    frequency: Int,
    frequencyUnit: TimeUnit,
    scheduleDays: [WeekDay],
    scheduleTime: Time
}

type Time

enum TimeUnit {
    MINUTE,
    HOUR,
    DAY,
    WEEK,
    MONTH
}

enum WeekDay {
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    SUNDAY
}
```

The resulting error message is:
`Type 'WeekDay' is declared as an enum in the GraphQL schema but is not a Java enum!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by creating a custom resolver for Scheduler and declaring the type and conversion there